# Can I get around the maximum time for a command being reached?

Tags: java, r, netlogo

I have a NetLogo model I'm running through RNetLogo. The model runs until a specified number of turtles remain and it records the number of ticks at this point.

I want to run the model 100 times but I get the error:

```
"Java-Object{java.lang.RuntimeException: Maximum time for NLDoCommandWhile reached. Process stopped.}"
```

Is there any way around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `max.minutes`-argument of the `NLDoCommandWhile`-function, which by default is set to 10 minutes ([see here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/RNetLogo/docs/NLDoCommandWhile)).

You can either increase it or set it to zero, which will let the model run as long as your condition is true (the danger here is obviously that your condition might never be met).